# unable to write to an ssl (openssl) socket after STARTTLS

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, smtp, starttls

Hi I'm trying to write a SMTP client in C++.
After the "ehlo ..." and the STARTTLS command, the connection seems to be fine I get this error when I try SSL_write() :

```
32096:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_write::ssl handshake failure
```

I tried SSL_do_handshake() before the SSL_write and it works.

Here's my code for the SSL part.

```
typedef struct {
    int socket;
    SSL *sslHandle;
    SSL_CTX *sslContext;
} SSLConnection;

SSLConnection* wrapSslSocket(SOCKET hSocket)
{
    SSLConnection *c;
    c = (SSLConnection *)malloc (sizeof (SSLConnection));
    c->sslHandle = NULL;
    c->sslContext = NULL;
    c->socket = hSocket;
    if (c->socket)
    {
        // Register the error strings for libcrypto & libssl
        SSL_load_error_strings ();
        // Register the available ciphers and digests
        SSL_library_init ();

        c->sslContext = SSL_CTX_new (SSLv23_client_method ()); //I tried SSLv23, SSLv3, SSLv2, TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1, TLSv1.0
        if (c->sslContext == NULL)
          ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);

        // Create an SSL struct for the connection
        c->sslHandle = SSL_new (c->sslContext);
        if (c->sslHandle == NULL)
          ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);

        // Connect the SSL struct to our connection
        if (!SSL_set_fd (c->sslHandle, c->socket))
          ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);

        if (!SSL_set_mode(c->sslHandle, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY))
            ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);

        // Initiate SSL handshake
        if (SSL_connect (c->sslHandle) != 1)
          ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
    }
    return c;
}



// Read all available text from the connection
int sslRead (SSLConnection *c)
{
  const int readSize = 1024;
  char buffer[1024];
  int cb;
  int cbBuffer = 0;

if (c)
{
    while (1)
    {       
        cb = SSL_read( c->sslHandle, buffer + cbBuffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1 - cbBuffer);
        if( cb <= 0 )
        {
            ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
            return -1;
        }
        cbBuffer += cb;
        if( memcmp( buffer + cbBuffer - 2, "\r\n", 2 ) == 0 )
        {
            buffer[cbBuffer] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}
    printf("ssl send : %s \n",buffer);
    char status[3];
    memcpy(status,buffer, 3*sizeof(char));
    status[3] = '\0';
    return atoi(status);
}

// Write text to the connection
int sslWrite (SSLConnection *c, char *text)
{
  if (c)
  {
      int v = SSL_do_handshake(c->sslHandle);
      ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
      return SSL_write (c->sslHandle, text, strlen (text));
  }
}
```

I'm testing on smtp.gmail.com port 587

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using Scott Gifford's `sslclient` (see http://www.superscript.com/ucspi-ssl/sslclient.html). sslclient will spawn your program and open an tcp connection to the server, and pipe your program's stdout to the server, and pipe output from the server to your program's stdin. He has a forked version for TLS that will start the connection off in plain text, then once the two sides have agreed on STARTTLS, your program can signal to sslcient to enable SSL encryption on the connection by writing a command to a file descriptor for this purpose (see https://github.com/SuperScript/ucspi-ssl/pull/1). Doing it this way, you can use sslclient to do all the heavy lifting as far as setting up the sockets and ssl, etc., and you can focus on the core function of your program.